# How do I make sure that update is called after action?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to update the `inputText` with the new value that is set by the `remoteCommnad`. I think the `update` is called by the time the value is not yet set on the server-side. Therefore my `inputText` remains empty/unchanged after the command went through.

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="sendUrl"
                 action="#{myBean.sendImgUrlToBean}"
                 update="image-url"/>
<p:inputText id="image-url"
             value="#{myBean.image.imageUrl}"/>
```

Along the way I tested with a `<p:commandButton value="update me" update="image-url"/>` below the inputText field to see if it would update. That worked out.

Comment: How are you calling the remote command?

Comment: @Melloware I am calling it with some javascript code. I am using it to pass some parameters to the bean like this: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/remotecommand?id=receiving-parameters

Should I post the js code?

Comment: You are aware that you are processing the entire form with your remote command?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I was not entirely sure. I surrounded my example with a `<h:form>`and it still does not work as intended.

Comment: YEs please post more code. I think we need to see the complete example.  Also you didn't mention your PrimeFaces version?